# Flutter Webview map

Tags: iphone, flutter, dart

I'm having a big map issue when I clicked the image button in the application bar. It looks like the webview has lost focus and is somehow locked and when I move the map, it acts like a zooming, but I only use one finger and want to move the map. I also have it in Stack view. But it works well on an Android phone / tablet.

I'm using webview_flutter: ^0.3.15+1.

It work well again if I reload map via controller, but I lost all map settings which I made before.
Is there some focus-again widget or something like this?

Thanks a lot for help, I've been stuck with this for days.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my plugin [flutter_inappbrowser](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappbrowser) (**EDIT**: it has been renamed to [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview)). You can load an url using `initialUrl`, a file inside assets folder (see more [here](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#load-a-file-inside-assets-folder)) using `initialFile` or load an html string using `initialData` directly.

An example of a google map inside the `InAppWebView` is presented below:

```dart
...

child: InAppWebView(
  initialFile: "assets/index.html",
  initialHeaders: {},
  initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
    inAppWebViewOptions: InAppWebViewOptions(
        debuggingEnabled: true,
    ),
  ),
  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
    webView = controller;
  },
  onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

  },
  onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

  },
  onConsoleMessage: (InAppWebViewController controller, ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
    print("console message: ${consoleMessage.message}");
  },
),

...
```

The `index.html` file inside the assets folder (example taken from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
          /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map */
          #map {
            height: 400px; /* The height is 400 pixels */
            width: 100%; /* The width is the width of the web page */
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
        <!--The div element for the map -->
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
          // Initialize and add the map
          function initMap() {
            // The location of Uluru
            var uluru = { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036 };
            // The map, centered at Uluru
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
              zoom: 4,
              center: uluru
            });
            // The marker, positioned at Uluru
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: uluru, map: map });
          }
        </script>
        <!--Load the API from the specified URL
        * The async attribute allows the browser to render the page while the API loads
        * The key parameter will contain your own API key (which is not needed for this tutorial)
        * The callback parameter executes the initMap() function
        -->
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

where `YOUR_API_KEY` is your google map key.